# How can I partition a QByteArray efficiently?

Tags: qt, string, substring, qstring, qbytearray

I want to partition a QByteArray message efficiently, so this function I implemented take the Bytes, the part I want to extract, and toEnd flag which tells if I want to extract part1 till the end of the array. my dilimeter is spcae ' '

example if I have:

```
ba = "HELLO HOW ARE YOU?"
ba1 = getPart(ba, 1, false) -> ba1 = "HELLO"
ba2 = getPart(ba, 2, true) -> ba2 = "HOW ARE YOU?"
ba3 = getPart(ba, 3, false) -> ba3 = "ARE"
```

the function below works just fine, but I am wondering if this is efficient. should I consider using split function?

```
QByteArray Server::getPart(const QByteArray message, int part, bool toEnd)
{
    QByteArray string;
    int startsFrom = 0;
    int endsAt = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < message.size(); i++)
    {
        if(message.at(i) == ' ')
        {
            count++;
            if(part == count)
            {
                endsAt = i;
                break;
            }
            string.clear();
            startsFrom = i + 1;
        }
        string.append(message.at(i));
    }
    if(toEnd)
    {
        for(int i = endsAt; i < message.size(); i++)
        {
            string.append(message.at(i));
        }
    }
    return string;
}
```

Comment: Related: [How to get substring from a string in qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23033112/how-to-get-substring-from-a-string-in-qt)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about this:

```
  QByteArray Server::getPart(const QByteArray& message, int part, bool toEnd)
  {
    int characters(toEnd ? -1 : message.indexOf(' ', part) - part);

    return message.mid(part, characters);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks JadziaMD, I had to change it little bit to get it to work the same way I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

Why not make it a regular QString and use [split](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#split). That will give you a QStringList.