# How to get substring from a string in qt?

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qstring, qregularexpression

I have a text form:

```
Last Name:SomeName, Day:23 ...etc
```

From Last Name:SomeName, I would like to get Last Name, and separately SomeName.

I have tried to use QRegularExpression,

```
QRegularExpression re("(?<label>\\w+):(?<text>\\w+)");
```

But I am getting the result:

```
QString label = match.captured("label") //it gives me only Name
```

What I want is whatever text till ":" to be label, and after to be text.

Any ideas?

Comment: Related: [How can I partition a QByteArray efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5978124/how-can-i-partition-a-qbytearray-efficiently)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use two different methods for this, based on your need:

- [split()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#split)
- [section()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#section)

#### main.cpp

```
#include <QString>
#include <QDebug>

int main()
{
    QString myString = "Last Name:SomeName, Day:23";
    QStringList myStringList = myString.split(',').first().split(':');
    qDebug() << myStringList.first() << myStringList.last();
    return 0;
}
```

#### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT = core
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

#### Build and Run

```
qmake && (n)make
```

#### Output

```
"Last Name" "SomeName"
```